# How to differentiate between a null from a non matched record and a null from a non existing record in a left join?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

The statements below create the tables, data and the select which has the issue.

The goal is when there are no orders for custid 1, I want to display 'Did not find any orders' and if there are order records for custid 1  but not for a TV, I want to display 'Found order but not TV order'. In both cases, t.description will be NULL but I need to differentiate between the two NULL cases. How to differentiate between them so that the first two WHEN statements can handle each accordingly?

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Customer](
    [CustId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [CustomerName] [varchar](50) NOT NULL
)

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Order](
    [OrderId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [CustId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Description] [varchar](50) NOT NULL
)



INSERT INTO customer (CustId, CustomerName) VALUES
(1, 'John'),
(2, 'Tom')
GO

INSERT INTO [order] (OrderId, CustId, Description) VALUES
(1, 2, 'TV')
go

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#temp') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #temp;

SELECT

    'TV' Description INTO #temp

SELECT c.CustId
    ,t.Description
   ,o.Description
   ,CASE
        WHEN t.Description IS NULL THEN 'Did not find any orders'
        WHEN t.Description IS NULL THEN 'Found order but not TV order'
        ELSE 'Found TV Order' 
    END Status

FROM Customer c
LEFT JOIN [Order] o
    ON o.CustId = c.CustId
LEFT JOIN #temp t
    ON t.Description = o.Description
WHERE c.CustId = 1
```

**UPDATE:**

The #temp table has the criteria to search for. In this case 'TV'.

Comment: `WHEN t.Description <> 'TV' THEN 'Found order but not TV order'`

Comment: i suggest simply add a count column you will get to know either it is there or not.

Comment: @Tony_Henrich . . . I cannot figure out what result set you want.  As written, you will get a separate row for each order (or at least each TV order) in the data.  The description, though suggests that you want one row per customer.  But if so, why are you including order information in the `SELECT`?

Comment: @GordonLinoff I added order information so show the info but yes the order is not in the select. I am expecting one row back

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to display information about a customer, use aggregation:

```
SELECT c.CustId,
       (CASE WHEN COUNT(o.CustId) = 0
             THEN 'Did not find any orders'
             WHEN SUM(CASE WHEN o.Description = 'TV' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 0
            THEN 'Found order but not TV order'
            ELSE 'Found TV Order' 
       END) as Status
FROM Customer c LEFT JOIN 
     [Order] o
     ON o.CustId = c.CustId
WHERE c.CustId = 1
GROUP BY c.CustId;
```

Note that I have no idea what `#temp` is being used for.

Also, you shouldn't be including order-level information in the `SELECT`if you want information at the customer-level.

Comment: This gives an error: Column 'Customer.CustId' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: @Tony_Henrich . . . I recommended the aggregation and then didn't include the `group by`.  It's fixed.

Answer (score 0):

///You Can try this.

```
 select a.custid,a.CustomerName,orderid=isnull(b.orderId,0),
     description=iif(b.description is null,'Did not Find Any Order',b.description) 
     from Customer a left join [Order] b on a.custid=b.Custid
```

Answer (score 0):

This might help you, not sure.

**case statement:**

```
,case when  t.Description = o.Description  then 'Found TV Order'
         when  isnull(t.Description,'No') = isnull(o.Description,'No') then 'Did not find any orders'
         when  isnull(t.Description,'No') <> isnull(o.Description,'No') then 'Found order but not TV order'
   end Status
```

**Modified Query:**

```
SELECT c.CustId
    ,t.Description tdesc
   ,o.Description odesc

   ,case when  t.Description = o.Description  then 'Found TV Order'
         when  isnull(t.Description,'No') = isnull(o.Description,'No') then 'Did not find any orders'
         when  isnull(t.Description,'No') <> isnull(o.Description,'No') then 'Found order but not TV order'
   end Status
  /*  ,CASE
        WHEN t.Description IS NULL THEN 'Did not find any orders'
        WHEN t.Description IS NULL THEN 'Found order but not TV order'
        ELSE 'Found TV Order' 
    END Status  */

FROM Customer c
LEFT JOIN [Order] o ON o.CustId = c.CustId
LEFT JOIN #temp t   ON t.Description = o.Description
```

[image]

> --------------------------- ** Old code is below **---------------------------------------------

```
 select CustId,descpt 
    from 
    (
    SELECT c.CustId
        , case when o.Description is null then 'Did not find any orders' end   descpt 
    FROM Customer c
    LEFT JOIN [Order] o ON o.CustId = c.CustId  ) no_orders
    where no_orders.descpt is not null

    union 
    select CustId,descpt 
    from 
    (
    SELECT c.CustId
        , case when o.Description ='TV' then 'Found order for TV ' end   descpt 
    FROM Customer c
    LEFT JOIN [Order] o ON o.CustId = c.CustId  ) no_orders
    where no_orders.descpt is not null

    union
    select CustId,descpt 
    from 
    (
    SELECT c.CustId
        , case when o.Description <> 'TV' then 'Found order but not TV order' end   descpt 
    FROM Customer c
    LEFT JOIN [Order] o ON o.CustId = c.CustId  ) no_orders
    where no_orders.descpt is not null
```

[image]

Comment: what's going to happen if there're 10 orders for one customer?

Comment: oh, It will return multiple rows for one customer.

Comment: modified the query

Comment: What I am asking for needs to be handling in a single case statement. Not multiple rows.

Comment: I have tried handling in a single case statement. Let me know if this has helped you

Answer (score 0):

It's not completely clear from the question, but I assume that temporary table `#temp` is list of descriptions you want to look in orders for.

So there're several different approaches I can think of, for example you can use `OUTER APPLY`:

```
select
    c.CustId,
    t.Description,
    case
        when o.Description is null then
            'Did not find any orders'
        when o.Description <> t.Description then
            concat('Found order but not ',t.Description,' order')
        else
            concat('Found ',t.Description,' order')
    end as status
from dbo.Customer as c
    cross join (
        select 'TV' as Description
    ) as t
    outer apply (
        select top 1 tt.Description
        from dbo.[Order] as tt
        where
            tt.CustId = c.CustId
        order by
            case when tt.Description = t.Description then 0 else 1 end
    ) as o
```

[<kbd>sql fiddle demo</kbd>](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/efe7e8/9)

Or you can use left join and outer apply:

```
select
    c.CustId,
    t.Description,
    case
        when o1.Description is not null then
            concat('Found ',t.Description,' order')
        when o2.OrderId is not null then
            concat('Found order but not ',t.Description,' order')
        else
            'Did not find any orders'
    end as status
from dbo.Customer as c
    cross join (
        select 'TV' as Description
    ) as t
    left join dbo.[Order] as o1 on
        o1.CustId = c.CustId and
        o1.Description = t.Description
    outer apply (
        select top 1 tt.OrderId
        from dbo.[Order] as tt
        where
            tt.CustId = c.CustId and
            tt.Description <> t.Description
    ) as o2
```

[<kbd>sql fiddle demo</kbd>](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/efe7e8/11)

Answer (score 0):

First, I am assuming there can and likely will be multiple records per Customer in the Order table.  Since you need to know if there are not any orders, but apparently need a result set, you can't filter out based on the desired description...  But you can if you group by the customer (and description) and use the count function and this also allows you to return a single record when there may be many in the Order table.

Also since you are ultimately trying to answer two questions based on two result sets (tv orders and any orders) then you are going to need some version of two queries.  Several options, but a subquery is the simplest.

Here is the SQL (I made the temp table permanent for this and also added more records):

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Customer](
    [CustId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [CustomerName] [varchar](50) NOT NULL
)
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Order](
    [OrderId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [CustId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Description] [varchar](50) NOT NULL
)
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[FakeTemp](
    [Description] [varchar](50) NOT NULL
)
INSERT INTO FakeTemp (Description) VALUES
('TV')
GO
INSERT INTO customer (CustId, CustomerName) VALUES
(1, 'John'),
(2, 'Tom'),
(3, 'Steve')
GO
INSERT INTO [order] (OrderId, CustId, Description) VALUES
(1, 1, 'TV')
go
INSERT INTO [order] (OrderId, CustId, Description) VALUES
(2, 2, 'VCR')
go
INSERT INTO [order] (OrderId, CustId, Description) VALUES
(3, 1, 'VCR')
go


select c.CustomerName, count(OrderId) as TV_Orders
, (select count(OrderID) from [order] where CustId = 1) as All_Orders
from customer c
left outer join [order] o on c.CustId = o.CustId
inner join FakeTemp t on o.Description = t.Description
where c.CustID = 1
group by c.CustomerName, t.Description
```

And here is the link to the fiddle (thanks to Roman Pekar for starting me off):
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/eadc3/16/0

I didn't do the case statement as I think you can easily turn this into the case statement needed to output the text, and this shows the results a bit better.

For those that couldn't finish out the Case Statement, here is the homework problem completed in its entirety:

```
select
  CASE
      WHEN (select count(OrderID) from orders where CustId = 1) = 0 THEN 'Did not find any orders'
      WHEN count(OrderID) = 0 THEN 'Found order but not TV order'
      ELSE 'Found TV Order'
  End as Status

from customer c
left outer join [orders] o on c.CustId = o.CustId
inner join FakeTemp t on o.Description = t.Description
where c.CustID = 1
group by c.CustomerName, t.Description
```

Comment: This does not answer my question in any form. The question is specific about using a case statement and displaying a certain text according to the type of data present.

Comment: @Tony_Henrich I added the case statement.